# Expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘char’ syntax error

Tags: c

I can't find this syntax error that reads:

> /home/ubuntu/workspace/stack.c:6:12: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘char’
>    char stack(char cmd[40])
>               ^

The ^ symbol being under the second c in stack(char, I've looked around and I can't find an answer, most of them are something simple like a ; at the end of the main function, but I can't see anything wrong with this. Anyone got an idea?

stack.c

```
#ifndef stack
#define stack
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stack.h"

char stack(char cmd[40])
{

stacks newstack()
{
    stacks s;
    s -> head = NULL;
    return s;
}

void deletestack(stacks s)
{
    node temp;
    while(s -> head)
    {
        temp = s -> head;
        s -> head = s -> head -> next;
        free(temp);
    }
    free(s);
}

int isEmpty(stacks s)
{
    if(s -> head == NULL)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

void push(stacks s, element e)
{
    node n = (node)malloc(sizeof(node_type));
    n -> e = e;
    n -> next = s -> head;
    s -> head = n;
}

element peek(stacks s)
{
   return s -> head -> e; 
}

void display(stacks s)
{
    while(s -> head)
    {
        printf("%d\n", s -> head -> e);
    }
}

element pop(stacks s)
{
    printf("%d\n", s -> head -> e);
    temp = s -> head;
    s -> head = s -> head -> next;
    free(temp);        
}



}
#endif
```

stack.h

```
#ifndef ____Linked_List_H____
#define ____Linked_List_H____

#include "stdheader.h"

//Structures

//element is content of a node.
typedef int element;

//node is 1 link in a linked list. 
struct _node{
  element e;
  struct _node* next;
};

typedef struct _node node_type;
typedef struct _node* node;

//linked list is a series of links tracked by the head or start of the list.                 struct _linked_list{
  node head;
};

typedef struct _linked_list stacks_type;
typedef struct _linked_list* stacks;

stacks newstack();
void deletestack(stacks);
int isEmpty(stacks);
element pop(stacks);
void push(stacks, element);
element peek(stacks);
void display(stacks);


#endif
```

Comment: This looks like you have a missing semicolon from `stack.h`. Can you post that code too? Also, you're trying to define functions inside of functions, which isn't allowed in C.

Comment: You missed something in the header file.

Comment: Identifiers starting with double-underscore are reserved for the implementation. Do not use them in user-code! And do not `typedef` pointer! That obfuscates the semantics and is invitation for logical faults in the code.

Comment: It's actually not my code, it's my professors, and he instructed us to use it so....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use #define stack and then later in the code, name a function stack. And you can't define functions inide a function.

Comment: Yeah that was it, thanks. First time working with multiple files in c, so I didn't really notice. Again, thanks.

Comment: There actually are more flaws and one error which likely generated the error.

Comment: Yeah I know, working through it now. It was just that that was one error that I couldn't get past at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define stack
```

This line tells the precompiler to exchange the symbol `stack` with nothing.

The precompiler will process this line:

```
char stack(char cmd[40])
```

into this:

```
char (char cmd[40])
```

Without a function name, the code is no longer valid C.

I don't see why the `#define` is needed, so I would just remove it.